# ActiveRecord - I created a record, but when i check if it exists it returns nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am having trouble either creating a record or checking if it exists. I'm submitting two entries to create, "id" and "uid", to the "Checks" controller. Migrations below:

create_checks

```
class CreateChecks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :checks do |t|
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

add_uid_to_checks

```
class AddUidToChecks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :checks, :uid, :string
  end
end
```

Checks_controller#create

```
def create
  @check = Check.new(check_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @check.save
      format.html { redirect_to @check, notice: 'Check was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @check }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @check.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Which gives me the following when submitted through ajax with two parameters - ID and UID

```
Started POST "/checks.json" for ::1 at 2016-09-05 09:36:31 -0500
Processing by ChecksController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"54545454", "uid"=>"23232323"}
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (2.0ms)  INSERT INTO "checks" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)
[["created_at", 2016-09-05 14:36:31 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-09-05 14:36:31 UTC
]]
   (10.0ms)  commit transaction
  Rendering checks/show.json.jbuilder
  Rendered checks/_check.json.jbuilder (1.0ms)
  Rendered checks/show.json.jbuilder (9.0ms)
Completed 201 Created in 201ms (Views: 174.8ms | ActiveRecord: 12.0ms)
```

Then I check to see if it exists using this controller...

```
def set_check
if Check.exists?(params[:id])
  render plain: "1"
else
  render plain: "0"
end
    end
```

Which gives me...

```
Started GET "/checks/54545454" for ::1 at 2016-09-05 0
9:36:37 -0500
Processing by ChecksController#show as */*
      Parameters: {"id"=>"54545454"}
Check Exists (1.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "checks" WHERE "checks"."id" = ? L
IMIT ?  [["id", 0], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering text template
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Filter chain halted as :set_check rendered or redirected
Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 1.8ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

And renders "0" for not found. I'm certain I'm doing something wrong, but I'm having trouble identifying where.

More code bits:

Routes.rb relevant section:

```
  resources :checks
```

Where set_checks is defined (at the top of the controller, right below class ChecksController < ApplicationController)

```
  before_action :set_check, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Comment: please add your routes code, and the place where `set_check` is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord uses the `id` column as a primary key - it is an auto-incrementing column so the value is set when you insert a record into the table. Thus you never pass an ID as the param when creating a new record.

In fact if you check the id of the newly created record it is not the same as the parameter:

```
def create
  @check = Check.new(check_params)
  logger.info("id param is: #{ params[:id] }")

  respond_to do |format|
    if @check.save
      logger.info("Check id is: #{ @check.id }")
      format.html { redirect_to @check, notice: 'Check was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @check }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @check.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Added - if you did not intend to mess with the primary key you should not use `id` as a column name.

Comment: You can use another type of primary keys such as a generated hash but you should really figure out what you are doing first.